# Factor out random variable from conditional expectation

Tags: probability

$X$ and $Y$ are dependent random variables. I have already proved that $E[X|Y=y] = E[X]$, but I'm having difficulty extending this result to $E[XY|Y=y]$.

Can we somehow use $E[X|Y=y] = E[X]$ to prove that $E[XY|Y=y] = yE[X]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
E[XY|Y=y]&=E[Xy|Y=y] \text{, we know the value of }Y \\
&= y E[X|Y=y] \text{, due to linearity} \\
&= yE[X]
\end{align}

Comment: Oh, I failed to see $y$ is actually a constant here. Thank you!